# Flex: air application update some files

Tags: apache-flex, air

I have 4 projects:

1.- AIR desktop application project (modular app) (app.swf 170kb)
2.- Controls/Components library project (1.2mb)
3.- Core library project (150kb)
4.- Styles/Skins/Assets library project (3.5mb)

2, 3, 4 are linked as RSL in 1
3, 4 are linked as External in 2
4 are linked as External in 3

I want to update only 1, 2, 3 and/or 4... For example, I want to update/upgrade only 1 and 2.

I tried with ApplicationUpdaterUI, building only files I needed, but this replace all folder content and paste the files archived on package.

I try packaging all files, manually extract the files from package and paste them (only files updated) in application folder, but doesn't work... If I paste the 4 swfs, application run perfectly...

I understand that Flex creates a placeholder for RSL libraries, but I think also that registers something like the CLSID of rsl swfs in app.swf.

I tried with ANT also... same results...

What are my options? Using Air Desktop Application...

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

2, 3 and 4 are linked "External".

In AIR application, I build all functions for check remote config (config.xml) file with library, modules and assets versions. The application download and save all swf files has needed to be updated. After that, application load all files with loader.loadBytes(). Default framework linkage is RSL.

Only AIR application must be updated with ApplicationUpdaterUI, but libraries, modules and assets (will be updated constantly) are updated on demand.

Sorry for my english.

I hope this help someone.